# How to query specific percentage of objects(e.g, 50,70,) in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

How can I query a particular percentage of database objects in Django ORM.
Am unable to use limiting query set as it requires that the length of objects be specified.
I only want get like 48 precent, 30 precent, or 70 Percent of the Django objects in the ORM..

Here's a sample code::

```
percentage = 60
results =Model.objects.filter()[: percentage].
```

**I simply need a way to query a particular percentage of the objects.**

Thanks friends.
I hope to hear from you all..

**Please note that I want to query percentage i.e. 60 percentage, not the exact number of query because I don't know the exact counts
Thanks**

Answer (score 2):

Will it be good for you if you get count from database? like that:

```
percentage = 0.6
limit = Model.objects.count() * percentage
results =Model.objects.filter()[:limit]
```

Comment: `Model.objects.filter().count() * percentage`

Comment: as filter is empty actually it doesn't need

Comment: In case it's needed we need to use `all()` but in case it's `filter` it should be used in `count` query as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, friends. I really appreciate it. Your solution works fine for me. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it

```
percentage = 60
results = Model.objects.filter()[:int(Model.objects.count() * percentage / 100)]
```